# Adding forms to joomla's front end component view

Tags: html, forms, joomla, components

I'm developing a component using joomla 3.0. I'm trying to add forms in my component. I saw that joomla has the JHTML class for adding forms in backend.

what is the recommendation for creating forms in frontend. should I use JHTML or clean html markup ? and where can I find docs for that class.

Comment: It really depends on what kind of form you need.  Personally, I'd look at the core forms, which use JForm, if you want to save to the database or do something like send a message from the contact form.  If you want to do things more like filters then you'd do JHTML like in the filter bar or sidebar in the back end.

Comment: This is a good question that I've wondered myself. Personally I've always just used clean html markup. @Elin, would love for you to expand on this in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[JForm](https://github.com/elinw/joomla-cms/tree/master/libraries/joomla/form)
[JModelForm](https://github.com/elinw/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/legacy/model/form.php)
[JControllerForm](https://github.com/elinw/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/legacy/controller/form.php)

Forms which save data in the databas in Joomla 1.6 + mainly use the JForm package which manages forms (xml or xml strings), fields (the actual fields) and rules (validation).

The normal way simple way to manage it is to extend JModelForm and JControllerForm.  If you look in the core you'll see these extended in places you might not expect such as the single contact view but basically that's because those classes provide the basic set up you need to manage a form on any part of your page even if the rest of it has nothing to do with forms.

Alternatively you can always create a new JForm object.

If you have a models folder usually you would have a forms folder and then if needed fields and rules folders. THe latter two contain any custom fields or rules you may need for your extension.  These will be found by default when building a form in your extension but if you want them from somewhere else you would need to use addFieldPath or addRulePath or addFormPath as needed in you form xml.

Jform provides a standard set of fields and rules as well as a standard list of filters.  Rules means validation while filters will change the saved values.  You can also use any filter available in JFilterInput.

If you give a field the same name as a field in the current table object the data will automatically be saved in that field.  if you use a fields tag with an name that matches a field by default the fields listed inside the tag will be saves as a JSON string within that field.

That's pretty much the basics, though  there is a lot more.

One important thing for me is that if you use JForm the default filtering is very good and you selectively allow html etc so by default it is very secure.